# How do i create a new text file of vehicle owners who have already exceeded the speed limit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compare, output

Suh basically there is a text file with information of numerous offenders who have exceeded the speed limit with their address, name and vehicle registration. one record looks like this in the text file:

```
reg: TW04AND
name: Karlie Kloss
address: 1 Hotstuff Road, BD7 4BT, Bradford
```

and then their is another file with another set of results with addresses who have just recently exceeded the speed limit with standard plate registration with an entry looking like this:

```
114mph = WE64NGL
```

or

```
78mph = XD01SMH
```

so that it will compare the two documents and produce another document with the reoffenders. I know how to create a new text file, however its the comparing and outputting that im struggling with and id appreciate if someone could help me.  thanks in advance :)

Comment: All you need to do it read both text files store them in a list and then iterate through them to find a match.

Answer (score 0):

Learning how to read a text file with python is a quick search away but anyway, here is a code example to fit one of your file structures.

Following this stucture

```
reg: TW04AND
name: Karlie Kloss
address: 1 Hotstuff Road, BD7 4BT, Bradford
```

The below code will read the text file and create a list containing dictionaries for each data set.

```
offender_lst = [] # List to contain each dictionary
d = {} # Create initial reference for d ( in case the first line doesn't start with reg )

with open("offender_lst.txt") as f: # Open the text file
    for line in f: # Iterate through the file
        line = line.strip() # remove \n character from line

        if not line: # If line is empty continue
            continue

        # If the line starts with reg overwrite d with empty dict
        if line.startswith("reg"):
            d = {}

        # Partition the line
        head, sep, tail = line.partition(": ")
        # Add them to dict
        d[head] = tail

        # If the line starts with address (last line of set)
        # Append the dict to list
        if line.startswith("address"):
            offender_lst.append(d)

print(offender_lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you could read all of the data from both files into a dictionary and store the offender information, using the plate as the key. Then just search by plates to check for prior speeding incidents as needed.

```
offenders = {}

def normalize_line(line, delim):
    normalized = " ".join(line.split())
    first, second= normalized.split(delim)
    return first.strip(), second.strip()

with open("offender_info.txt") as f:
    line = f.readline()
    while line:
        if line.startswith("reg"):
            # parse plate line
            _, plate = normalize_line(line, ':')
            # parse name line
            _, name = normalize_line(f.readline(), ':')
            # parse address line
            _, address = normalize_line(f.readline(), ':')

            # save offender
            offenders[plate] = {
                'name': name,
                'address': address,
                'speeding_incidents': [],
            }

        line = f.readline()

with open("speeding_incidents.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        speed, plate = normalize_line(line, '=')
        offenders[plate]['speeding_incidents'].append(speed)

print(offenders)
```